# Django back end with a dynamic front end (Angularjs)?

Tags: angularjs, django

My friend and I are looking to develop a very simple web app. Simply put we want a front page that dynamically updates from a database. So far we've been on on the Django path but have found that maybe this is not the best option in terms of dynamically updating webpages. I've looked at SwampDragon but it seems pretty new and has a sparse community.

Is it possible for us to write what we want purely with Django and AngularJS or should we be looking at an entirely different stack for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, Django and Angular work fine together.  Angular is usable with any backend or framework you would like to use.  A quick google search yields some helpful links:

https://github.com/jrief/django-angular - Looks to ease the integration between Django and Angular.  Also good for performing basic operations.  Link to the docs and a demo in the readme

https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial/ - Thinkster tutorial, this is a good site for other angular resources as well.

You will basically be using Django as an API that your Angular app will call.

Alternatively, you may think that Django is too heavy for your app and you want something a little smaller.  In these cases, most people recommend [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).  If you are interested in only using Flask as an API, you can get started using [this](http://www.flaskapi.org/) flask extension.  Hopefully these links will get you started.